# How can I add '%' into values?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

i want to make this, but i don't know how I can....

```
$opacities: (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90);

@each $opacity in $opacities {
   .bg-opacity-#{$opacity}-#{$color} {
      background-color: rgba($value, $opacity+%);
   }
}
```

Because I want this result

```
.bg-opacity-2-primary {
   background-color: rgba(20,15,45, 0.2);
}
```

But this is not possible. I haven't found a solution for this

Comment: you just need to divide the value you have by 100, that will make it go from 0 to 1, which is how rgba opacity is represented

Comment: can u make an example, plz?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved above issue related to the SCSS each loop. Please try this to solve your problem.

**SCSS Code**

```
$color:red;

$opacities: (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90);

@each $opacity in $opacities {
    .bg-opacity-#{$opacity}-#{$color} {
        background-color: rgba($color, $opacity/100);
     }
}
```

**CSS output**

```
.bg-opacity-10-red {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.bg-opacity-20-red {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.bg-opacity-30-red {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
} ...
```

And also for more information related to SCSS each loop, go to [Learnopidia - SCSS Each loop Article](https://learnopidia.com/scss-each-loop/).